# EHOSTUNREACH when connecting to Places API

Tags: java, android, routes, google-places-api

I'm getting address suggestions in my Android app using the Google Places API. This is the relevant code where the call is made:

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AdapterClass";
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
private static final String TYPE_DETAILS = "/details";
private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";
private static final String API_KEY = "somekey24534535345";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
sb.append("?sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
```

This has always worked perfectly, until today I received a log report from a device (located in India, if that matters) throwing the following exception at the last line in the code above:

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4003:c01::5f (port 443): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)\n\tat libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)\n\tat java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)\n\tat java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)\n\tat com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)\n
```

What could be the reason for that? In particular I don't understand the stack trace where it gives the address "maps.googleapis.com/2404:6800:4003:c01::5f" which appears nowhere in the code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The numbers part is an IPv6 network address.  Seems like he's having network issues.  This is more likely a carrier problem then something you can fix.

You do have 1 big problem in your code though-  you assume that the user has connectivity.  He may not-  simply walking through some buildings I may lose connectivity.  That shouldn't cause your app to crash.  Anything that does network IO should be wrapped in try/catch blocks that catch exceptions like this and return an appropriate error message to the user (even just a Toast that says "Try again later") rather than letting the exception fall through and crashing.

Comment: the code above is just a snippet to show the part concerning the address and the connection, of course I use try/catch in the complete code. It seems strange though that I can't fix this somehow. The user seems to have a good internet connection, everything else in the app works well, even other google services create no issues except this one...